# RxSwift crashes when running UnitTest on XCode 9.3

Tags: swift, xcode, swift4, xctest, rx-swift

did anyone face RxSwift crash on XCode 9.3? here is the function that causes the problem

```
func setupValidation(result: Variable<ValidationState>, testValues: Observable<Bool>...) {
let disposeBag: DisposeBag = DisposeBag()
Validation
  .combine(testValues)
  .bind(to: result)
  .disposed(by: disposeBag)}
```

here is the error:

> Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:   "(extension in
>   RxCocoa):RxSwift.ObservableType.bind(to: RxSwift.Variable) ->
>   RxSwift.Disposable"

Comment: When does this crash occur?

Comment: when I try to run the unit test

Comment: Compile/build or run?

Comment: running unit test

Comment: @KaraBenNemsi I have updated my post you can check

Comment: might this be related to your problem https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/issues/1583

Comment: @KaraBenNemsi thanks a lot you saved my day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably related to [this](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/issues/1583). Try adding adding `import RxCocoa` and `import RxSwift` to the unit test files to solve the linker build error.